# Can I integrate node.js to my C++ exe, for executing some JS code?

Tags: node.js, packaging

I want to integrate Node.js to my C++ application for some JS code execution? How can that be done?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/embedding.html

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is not a linkable library from C++.  It is its own process and is designed to run that way. You would probably find it best to launch a child process from your C++ app to run whatever it is you want to run.

You could of course take the V8 JavaScript engine and integrate it into your C++ app which is exactly what Node.js did itself, but that is no small undertaking and then you still have to put a run-time library around it if you want to be able to do anything other than pure JavaScript (like you want to talk to anything in the outside world) since V8 is only a pure JavaScript engine - it can't do networking or talk to a file system or prompt the user or anything like that.

Probably best to just run Node.js as a child process unless you're up for a big effort.

FYI, the code for Node.js is all public [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node) so, with a little research, you can find anything you want related to Node.js there.